# How to switch to a screen with two digit index in screen command?

Tags: gnu-screen

Let's say we have opened more than 10 screens in the `screen` program. How to switch to a screen using Ctrl+A, n where n > 9?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three ways to do it

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> will give you a graphical list of your windows that you can
   scroll around in.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> will give you a prompt to type a screen number.
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> (or <kbd>p</kbd>) will take you next window, let us say you are on window 9 and if you press this, it will take you to next (or previous) window

Comment: I would say that the second way is closest.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use: **C-a "**

or you can use: **C-a '** this will open a switch to window prompt where you can type in any number.